# Facebook is not displaying the email id info in the auth dialog box

Tags: facebook, permissions, authorization

I have integrated Facebook with my web application.

When the Facebook authorization dialog is displayed to tht user, it displays only basic info 
details. There is no email id displayed.

It is used to display the email id also earlier. It stopped to display the email id.

What I am missing? Has FB done any changes in the auth dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for 'email' permission. Check it out here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/